# Laravel Cors issue when setting header.Authorization on request

Tags: laravel-5, authorization, axios, token

I have successfully set `cors` middleware with Laravel as describer [here](https://gist.github.com/drewjoh/43ba206c1cde9ace35de154a5c84fc6d)

Therefore, this ajax call is ok

```
        axios.get('http://my_domain/api/my_api')
```

But when trying to send token like this:

```
        axios.get('http://my_domain/api/my_api',
            {
              headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer aaa.bbb.ccc'
              }
            })
```

I get a cors erros saying `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I have even added `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in the middleware, I still have the issue.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Log;

class Cors {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        Log::info("Using cors for ".$request->url());
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization');
    }
}
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I earnestly tried to find solution on this, and here is what resolved mine. I had to add 03 edits **simultaneously**:

1) Add the cors in route middleware

```
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        ...
        'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    ];
```

2) Add the cors in global middlewre

```
    protected $middleware = [
        ...
        \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    ];
```

3) Add custom `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in Cors middleware `app/Http/Middleware/Cors.php`

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Log;

class Cors {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        Log::info("Using cors for " . $request->url());
        return $next($request)
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With');// <-- Adding this
    }
}
```

If someone can explain why it worked, that would be great to understand its behavior.